# Synchronizing threads to perform actions sequentially

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a method

```
public static synchronized void print(String message, int sleepTime) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(message);
    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
}
```

Calling this method prints whatever message I give it and causes the thread that called it to pause for a specified moment. The `static synchronized` makes it so that multiple threads of this class must synchronize their `print` so that no thread may begin printing before another thread is finished sleeping (except for the first thread to call `print` of course)

Somewhere else in my code, I have the calling thread doing this:

```
print("some message", 1000);
print("some other message", 1000);
```

Every trial I've run using this code resulted in all threads printing the first message "some message" first, followed by all threads printing "some other message" last.

For example, if I have 3 threads, the expected results are as follows (which I could get them when I run the code for few times):

```
some message
some message
some message
some other message
some other message
some other message
```

Admittedly, I haven't run that many trials.

But, I suspect that a thread that finishes printing the first message (let's call this thread A) would then compete against other threads that may not have printed the first message yet (let's call one such thread B).
Is it possible that the scheduler picks A a second time before picking B for the first time, thus causing the second message to be printed somewhere *before* all instances of the first message are finished printing?

In other words, is it possible that this could happen:

```
some message
some message
some other message
some message
some other message
some other message
```

If the above sequence is possible, how can I ensure that it does not happen? How can I guarantee that the first sequence is the one that *always* happens?

Comment: What do you mean by first sequence ? Both of your last two questions are contradictory ?

Comment: by first sequence, i mean the one that prints all the "some message" lines first before printing all "some other message" lines. The second sequence is the one with the interchanging messages. I refer to each block of code a sequence.

Comment: okay, but why do you want to do that ? The objective is not very clear.

Comment: @javaguy ah, sorry that it wasn't clear enough. My goal was to find a way of making multiple threads executing concurrently to synchronize in such a way that it'll perform all of one kind of action followed by all of another kind of action. When the threads are all executing the same kind of action, I do not need them to follow a strict sequential order. I wanted to find a way to achieve this behavior without using semaphores or other special synchronization tools.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by possible. There is absolutely no rule that prohibits it. However, the specific design choices made in the implementation you are using might make it such that it can't actually happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that the scheduler picks A a second time before picking
>   B for the first time, thus causing the second message to be printed
>   somewhere before all instances of the first message are finished
>   printing ?

Yes, this is possible that the Thread scheduler can pick the same thread again.

Also, one parameter that you might be interested and you need to double check is that **both of the threads are of the same priority or NOT**, which might cause thread Starvation as explained [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html), which leads the same thread running again and again. Just to add, you can set the priority to a `Thread` by calling `setPriority(int newPriority)` as given in the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: the link isn't working for me but I think I know what you're getting at. Basically a thread of a lower priority will never get to run if there's always a stream of higher priority threads in whatever queue the scheduler picks from, right?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is possible. I ran a simple multi-threaded program which has 3 Threads and i did get the interlocking messages that you wanted.

```
public class ThreadSyncTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadSyncTest t = new ThreadSyncTest();
        TempThread r1 = t.new TempThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);

        TempThread r2 = t.new TempThread();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

        TempThread r3 = t.new TempThread();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }

    public static synchronized void print(String message, int sleepTime) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(message);
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

    }

    class TempThread implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    print("some message", 1000);
                    print("some other message", 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Results:

```
some message
some message
some other message
some message
some other message
some message
some message
some other message
some message
some other message
```